# Fluent logger log to Fluent Bit

Tags: fluentd, fluent-bit

Can [Fluent logger](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang) log to [Fluent Bit](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit) remotely? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent logger uses Fluentd Forward protocol, so Fluent Bit can receive logs from Fluent logger. Check [the document](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/input/forward).